# iOS location authorization status change uncaught

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

I have a virtual machine with xcode and swift 1.2
with some code including this:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) { 
    //if authorized "do stuff"
}
```

It works as expected it catches me allowing the location service in the settings which it previously opens. Then it "does stuff. On my phyisical mac with swift 2 this is not the case. I allow location and debugger wont catch the changes.

The reasons elude me. Any hint in the right direction will be appreciated.

Comment: I must correct myself the code "do stuff" gets executed. The code is UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(strin:"www.google.com")!). So the difference is now when going to this "callback" - i.e. when the location manager caught the change it wont open browser and go to this site. Whereas it does work outside this callback. Mind that this thing works in 1.2 swift